# Consider the set, A of continuous functions $f:[0,1]→\mathbb R$ that satisfy :$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)(1−f(x))dx=\frac{1}{4}$,then find the cardinality of A

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, real-numbers

Consider the set,$ \ A$ of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ that satisfy : $\int_0^{1}f(x)(1-f(x))dx=\frac{1}{4}$,then what is the cardinality of $ \ A$?

I wanted to know how to initiate this problem,I'm thinking of only "**hit and trial,$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$**" method but it seems very much tedious.

I just wanted to know is there any specific method to solve $\int_0^{1}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{4}+\int_0^{1}(f(x))^2dx$...

Please give your suggestions...

thank you

**My attempt**

Let $g(x)=f(x)(1-f(x))$,then clearly $g(x)$ satisfies Rolle's theorem on $[0,1]$,so there exists $c\in [0,1]$ such that $g'(c)=0$

Now,$g'(c)=f'(c)-2f(c)f'(c)=0\implies f'(c)[1-2f(c)]=0\implies f'(c)=0 $ or $f(c)=\frac{1}{2}\ $

Now,if we choose $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$,then it will satisfy $\int_0^{1}f(x)(1-f(x))dx=\frac{1}{4}$.

So,**one possibility** is $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$,but it does not rule out the other possibilities.

*My Confusion:* (1) *How does Rolle's theorem is directing to this possiblity or it is just a mere hoax?*

(2) *If Rolle's theorem is correctly used then why it is not exploring the other possibilities?*

Comment: Arrange it so that on one side of the equation you have a $0$.

Comment: Hint: What values can $a(1-a)$ take for real $a$? What upper bound does this imply for your integral? What follows if you only allow for continuous $f$?

Comment: @Benjamin:$a(1-a)$ is maximized if $a=1-a\implies a=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

A very fast solution is given by $$\int_0^{1}f(x)(1-f(x))\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{4}\iff\int_0^{1}\frac14-f(x)(1-f(x))\,\mathrm dx=0\iff\int_0^1\frac{(2f(x)-1)^2}4\,\mathrm dx=0,$$

since $\frac14-f(x)(1-f(x))=\frac{(2f(x)-1)^2}4$.

(This can be found "intuitively" by maximizing $f(x)(1-f(x))$ for $f(x)\in \mathbb R$ and noting that the maximum is $\frac14$.)

Answer (score 1):

In general when you see things like $K = a(1-a)$, you can mess around a little by saying "Let $a = b + \frac12$"; then $K$ becomes $K = (b+\frac12)(1 - (b+\frac12) = (\frac12 + b)(\frac12 - b) = \frac14 - b^2$. [This is just "completing the square" for a particularly common pattern.]

After that, your problem becomes easy, as others have shown.

So the lesson here (to the degree that there is one) is "symmetrize about the average" (in this case the average being the average of $0$ and $-1$).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the function f(x) should be defined the following way, f: (0,1)---> R. Notice here that I have used () instead of [] to emphasise the fact that our function is defined from an open interval to an open interval.
If this was not the case, our definition would not be in accordance with the Extreme Value Theorem.

P.S. According to the Extreme Value Theorem for this continuous function :  image of the interval [0,1] must have a maximum value and a minimum value, hence the image cannot be the complete real line.